# H2 Database Embedded not working

Tags: java, h2

Good Day,

I am trying to use H2 in embedded mode on my Java Application. Basically, not only do i need to modify my H2 database within my Java App, but I also want to access the web interface so i can see the data.

This is my code:

```
final String[] args = new String[] {
        "-tcpPort", "8092",
        "-tcpAllowOthers","true" };
private static org.h2.tools.Server serverDB;
serverDB = org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer(args).start();
```

I have then tried to access my server via the Port 8092 at localhost and i get nothing. running the .jar file directly however allows me to access the server via safari. Can I know what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah okay, it was apparently this

```
serverDB=org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer("-webAllowOthers").start();
```

Comment: By the way, to allow remote connections to the TCP server (`createTcpServer`), it's `-tcpAllowOthers`.

Comment: any idea how to set the port of the web server?

Comment: Well, the TCP port is `-tcpPort`, what do you think the web-port could be? By the way, please note the `true` after `-tcpAllowOthers` is not needed. See [the documentation](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#main_String...).

Comment: I tried String params="-webAllowOthers,-webPort, 8092"; didnt work